# React app throwing axios_1.default.post is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I am working on a React application using TypeScript. I have the following simple post method:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

await axios.post('api/account/register', {
    FirstName: formData.firstName,
    LastName: formData.lastName,
    Username: formData.email,
    Password: formData.password,
    IsLocked: true,
    Role: 'Admin',
});
```

Below is the corresponding code from the js file:

```
const axios_1 = __importDefault(require("axios"));
const react_1 = __importStar(require("react"));

yield axios_1.default.post('api/account/register', {
    FirstName: formData.firstName,
    LastName: formData.lastName,
    Username: formData.email,
    Password: formData.password,
    IsLocked: true,
    Role: 'Admin',
});
```

It throws this exception: **axios_1.default.post is not a function error**. I have the latest version of axios installed.

[image]

[image]

Below is the `ts.config` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    
  }
}
```

`dependencies` inside package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    //other packages   
    "axios": "1.4.0"
  },
```

Here you can find almost all project files:

https://github.com/erkaner/reactapp-peeraid

I have checked some other posts but could not find a solution to this problem. Any help?

Comment: Could you search in the whole project for this term `axios_1` using `ctrl + shift + f`?

Comment: @Joseph I have updated my code. It is in the js file corresponding to the TSX file.

Comment: looks like you run built `cjs` code in a browser env? if so, this doesn't work definitely

Comment: @tmhao2005 can you elaborate more on this? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you should provide a minimal reproducible repo so that we know the way you run your app

Comment: @tmhao2005 you mean this? https://github.com/erkaner/reactapp-peeraid

Comment: Yeah this is what I meant but where are your changes?

Comment: @tmhao2005 but which changes you mean? :(

Comment: I didn’t see where your axios is being used in the repo above

Comment: @tmhao2005 now I got all the files uploaded to the repo. Here is the link to the file where axios is used: https://github.com/erkaner/reactapp-peeraid/blob/master/src/_components/authentication/Register.tsx

Comment: how do i reproduce the problem no problem if i run `pnpm start`

Comment: @renakre Does your original setup look exactly the same as it's in the repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After testing and debugging extensively, and going to different sources to find out about the issue, the issue actually is with the `create-react-app`. Essentially, `axios` provides a `commonjs` module for browser, and the webpack config of the `create-react-app` doesn't seem to be handling it properly. [This](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12700) issue helped me confirm it.

### What did I do?

I went into the `Register.js` file and added a `console.log` for `axios__1` to find out, that it's -

```ts
{
  default: "/static/media/axios.77dc18bde70a91f68d85.cjs"
}
```

[image: axios instance]

which didn't make any sense, I saw that the extension is `.cjs` and also found out that if I delete all the `.js` files from the project, it works!. Why? All the files are es modules and webpack (from the `Register.js` source) seems to be importing `axios` as an es module -

```ts
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const axios_1 = __importDefault(require("axios"));
```

See here that the `__esModule` is set to `true`, so it'll try to import it like so. Now, as mentioned at the start, it's the `create-react-app`'s fault for incorrect webpack config, so read on.

### So, how to fix it?

Override the webpack config of the `create-react-app` to make sure the babel properly transpiles and imports the code. We can make use of [craco](https://craco.js.org/) or [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). I decided to go with `react-app-rewired` -

1. Install `react-app-rewired` with `npm i -D react-app-rewired`.
2. create a file `config-overrides.js` at the project root, and fill it up with this code snippet -

```ts
const getCacheIdentifier = require('react-dev-utils/getCacheIdentifier');

const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';

module.exports = function override(config, webpackEnv) {
  console.log('overriding webpack config...');

  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';
  const loaders = config.module.rules[1].oneOf;

  loaders.splice(loaders.length - 1, 0, {
    test: /\.(js|mjs|cjs)$/,
    exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: {
      babelrc: false,
      configFile: false,
      compact: false,
      presets: [
        [
          require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
          { helpers: true },
        ],
      ],
      cacheDirectory: true,
      // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
      cacheCompression: false,
      // @remove-on-eject-begin
      cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
        isEnvProduction
          ? 'production'
          : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
        [
          'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
          'babel-preset-react-app',
          'react-dev-utils',
          'react-scripts',
        ]
      ),
      // @remove-on-eject-end
      // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
      // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
      // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
      sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
      inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
    },
  });

  return config;
};
```

3. Modify the `package.json` to use `react-app-rewired` instead of `react-scripts`, like so -

```ts
...

  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },

...
```

And that's it, that'll resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is a fantastic answer! I wish I could invite you for a cup of coffee.

Comment: What could I have done to avoid this issue in the first place?

Comment: And I would come if I could. I think using a typescript cra template and then using a build from that, instead of bootstrapping a js cra and then adding typescript to that, ***probably*** would've prevented it.

Comment: In config-overrides.js I had to replace the line
`const loaders = config.module.rules[1].oneOf`
with
`config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.oneOf).oneOf`
and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from typescript `config` file so all you need is to make sure that you enable feature called `esModuleInterop`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // Other options...
  }
}
```

This option helps with importing CommonJS modules, which includes libraries like `axios`

for more info check this [`part`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) from docs

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have double checked the ts.config file, which is shared in the OP now. I think I have "esModuleInterop" set to true. Do you observe anything wrong or missing in it?

Comment: Also, is it okay to have axios under `dependencies` or `devDependencies` inside package.json?

Comment: Add  `axios` on `dependencies` section

Comment: yes I have it there actually.

Comment: I think the config file looks fine now

Answer (score 0):

I think problem comes with the import statements and how you're using `axios` in your TypeScript code. The `axios` library could be imported and used in the following manner:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const formData = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@example.com',
    password: 'securepassword',
  };

  const postData = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post('api/account/register', {
        FirstName: formData.firstName,
        LastName: formData.lastName,
        Username: formData.email,
        Password: formData.password,
        IsLocked: true,
        Role: 'Admin',
      });
      console.log('Post request successful');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in post request:', error);
    }
  };
```